# LayoutTransition - Expanding a container does not push other containers

Tags: android

Hello Android developers !

Nota: all code at the end of the post.

I want to animate a ViewGroup whenever one of it's child view turns visible with a smooth expand animation.
With the help of `LayoutTransition`, there is no problem for this expand/collapse animation.

But the problem is that the animated `ViewGroup` is part of a "complex" `LinearLayout`.

This `ViewGroup's` height is set to `wrap_content` and another `ViewGroup`, below the animated ViewGroup has a 0dp height and a weight set to 1 to fit all the remaining space on the screen.

Whenever the animated `ViewGroup` expands, as it takes more space vertically, the bottom `ViewGroup` should shrink to give the top `ViewGroup` the needed space to extend. And I want this bottom `ViewGroup` to shrink with an animation too.

What is not working is that the bottom `ViewGroup` is resized instantly when the animation on the first `ViewGroup` starts. I tried to add a LayoutTransition object to the bottom ViewGroup or to the global root ViewGroup but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Has anyone already managed to do such animation ? I want this to be 4.0-compatible. (no LayoutTransition.CHANGING then ... :s)

Thanks for the help !

Code now :

my_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actionbar_height"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_texture_black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- This is the layout with the LayoutTransition instance -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_margin_xlarge"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_margin_xlarge"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_medium"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_margin_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_black_gradient_to_top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_xxlarge"
            android:text="@string/text_my_documents"/>

        <!-- This is the layout with the extra content that is hidden/shown to trigger the animation -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_search_parameters"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_medium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_medium"
                android:text="TEST"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The bottom layout that fit all the remaining space vertically -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_central"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/debug">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java :

```
// activity initialization is hidden. This method is triggered whenever the title is clicked. It open the extra layout in the header ViewGroup.
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void openSearchParametersView() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        LayoutTransition transitioner = new LayoutTransition();
        transitioner.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.APPEARING);
        transitioner.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, 0);
        transitioner.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, transitioner.getDuration(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING));
        transitioner.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 0);
        headerViewGroup.setLayoutTransition(transitioner);
        centralViewGroup.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition()); // this does nothing :(
    }
    searchParametersView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Nobody has a single clue of how to perform such an animation ? :(